# How to install http-parser package in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I'm trying to install this http-parser in Ubuntu, but cannot find the proper way on their github :

https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser

Could you please advise ?

Comment: you can install by using Makefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instruction should work for any recent Ubuntu environment ([YMMV](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary%22YMMV%22)):

```
# install git, gcc and make (among the others)
sudo apt install git build-essential

# go to your home and clone the latest version of the project there 
cd && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser

# go inside the project directory, compile and install with superuser privileges
cd http-parser && make && sudo make install
```

Something could miss since I've installed a lot of packages already, keep me informed about any compilation issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Should I do ./configure before the make command ? I don't have git, can I just download and unzip? It would be nice if each repo can include "fork" the basic installation process by default in the read me

Comment: @Ilan: I've tested the above procedure, `./configure` is not needed (actually it does not exists at all). Download the [current latest release](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser/archive/v2.8.0.zip) as an alternative to install `git` and proceed. Note that you can't avoid installing `build-essential` unless they are already present on your system.

Comment: I think it went well

Comment: @Ilan: happy to know it. Happy hacking :)